# I need to scrap different types of prices from website using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to take price from website, but there is a problem, because there are products with and without discounts and prices for these discount and non discount are located in different "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbGAe.png) span". My code take only first price in website (btw website https://ua.iherb.com/new-products?p=1)

this is part of code

def get_page_data(html):
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

```
lis = soup.find_all('div', class_="product-cell-container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6")

for li in lis:
    try:
        name = li.find('div', class_='absolute-link-wrapper').find('a').get('title')
    except:
        name = ''

    try:
        url = li.find('div', class_='absolute-link-wrapper').find('a').get('href')
    except:
        url = ''

    prices = li.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"product-price-top"})
    main_list=[]
    for price in prices:
        try:
            discount_price = price.find("span", class_='price discount-green').text.strip()
            main_list.append(discount_price)

        except AttributeError:

            original_price = price.find("span", class_='price ').text.strip()
            main_list.append(original_price)

    print(main_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scrape the AJAX API accessed by Javascript to bring the information into page. Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

s = requests.Session()
big_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in tqdm(range(1, 400, 50)):
    df = pd.json_normalize(s.get(f'https://ua.iherb.com/catalog/iherblive?isAjax=true&index={x}&nop=50&_=1665000595915').json())
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
big_df.drop('Product.RatingStarsMap', axis=1, inplace=True)
big_df.to_csv('ukr_herbs.csv')
print(big_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
8/8 [00:04<00:00, 1.69it/s]
Country CountryCode Index   Product.Id  Product.Name    Product.ProductUrl  Product.ProductImage    Product.ProductImageRetina  Product.PartNumber  Product.ListPrice   Product.DiscountPrice   Product.OutOfStock  Product.StockStatus Product.HidePrice   Product.Discontinued    Product.NotAvailable    Product.ShowDiscount    Product.DiscountType    Product.IsInCartDiscount    Product.Rating  Product.RatingCount Product.RatingText  Product.RatingURL   Product.ReviewURL   Product.IsShippingSaver Product.IsFeaturedBrand Product.IsAutoship  Product.ShowGroupMessage    Product.IsProductCompared   Product.IsSeasonallyUnavailable Product.DiscountPercentage  Product.PrimaryImageIndex   Product.CartProductsInfo.lineItems  Product.HasRating   Product.HasTag  Product.SalesDiscountPercentage Product.IsAutoApplyPromo    Product.IsNew   Product.IsTrial Product.SpecialDealInfo.PercentageClaimed   Product.SpecialDealInfo.IsCompletelyClaimed Product.SpecialDealInfo.CountPerCustomer
0   Mexico  mx  1   18492   Thorne Research, Bio-Gest, 180 Capsules https://www.iherb.com/pr/thorne-research-bio-gest-180-capsules/18492    https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/thr/thr40502/k/13.jpg https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/thr/thr40502/r/13.jpg THR-40502   $44.00  $44.00  False   0   False   False   False   False   7   False   4.8 1284    4.8 of 5 based on 1284  https://www.iherb.com/pr/thorne-research-bio-gest-180-capsules/18492#product-detail-reviews https://www.iherb.com/r/thorne-research-bio-gest-180-capsules/18492 False   False   False   False   False   False   0   13  [{'productId': 18492, 'productName': 'Thorne Research, Bio-Gest, 180 Capsules', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/thr/thr40502/s/13.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/thr/thr40502/m/13.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 44.00′,′′:′ 44.00', 'PartNumber': 'THR-40502'}]   True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
1   Israel  il  2   103768  LoveBug Probiotics, Baby Probiotics, 6-12 Months, 4 Billion CFU, 30 Single Serve Stick Packs    https://www.iherb.com/pr/lovebug-probiotics-baby-probiotics-6-12-months-4-billion-cfu-30-single-serve-stick-packs/103768    https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lvb/lvb00033/k/28.jpg https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lvb/lvb00033/r/28.jpg LVB-00033   $22.49  $22.49  False   0   False   False   False   False   0   False   4.8 125 4.8 of 5 based on 125   https://www.iherb.com/pr/lovebug-probiotics-baby-probiotics-6-12-months-4-billion-cfu-30-single-serve-stick-packs/103768#product-detail-reviews https://www.iherb.com/r/lovebug-probiotics-baby-probiotics-6-12-months-4-billion-cfu-30-single-serve-stick-packs/103768 False   False   False   False   False   False   0   28  [{'productId': 103768, 'productName': 'LoveBug Probiotics, Baby Probiotics, 6-12 Months, 4 Billion CFU, 30 Single Serve Stick Packs', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lvb/lvb00033/s/28.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lvb/lvb00033/m/28.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 22.49′,′′:′ 22.49', 'PartNumber': 'LVB-00033'}] True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
2   United States   us  3   8647    Now Foods, Modified Citrus Pectin, 800 mg, 180 Veg Capsules https://www.iherb.com/pr/now-foods-modified-citrus-pectin-800-mg-180-veg-capsules/8647  https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now03075/k/7.jpg  https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now03075/r/7.jpg  NOW-03075   $55.86  $55.86  False   0   False   False   False   False   0   False   4.7 137 4.7 of 5 based on 137   https://www.iherb.com/pr/now-foods-modified-citrus-pectin-800-mg-180-veg-capsules/8647#product-detail-reviews   https://www.iherb.com/r/now-foods-modified-citrus-pectin-800-mg-180-veg-capsules/8647   False   False   False   False   False   False   0   7   [{'productId': 8647, 'productName': 'Now Foods, Modified Citrus Pectin, 800 mg, 180 Veg Capsules', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now03075/s/7.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now03075/m/7.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 55.86′,′′:′ 55.86', 'PartNumber': 'NOW-03075'}]  True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
3   United States   us  4   101229  Blithe, Pressed Serum, Tundra Chaga, 1.68 fl oz (50 ml) https://www.iherb.com/pr/blithe-pressed-serum-tundra-chaga-1-68-fl-oz-50-ml/101229  https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/blt/blt66010/k/2.jpg  https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/blt/blt66010/r/2.jpg  BLT-66010   $38.00  $34.20  False   0   False   False   False   True    1   False   4.6 9667    4.6 of 5 based on 9667  https://www.iherb.com/pr/blithe-pressed-serum-tundra-chaga-1-68-fl-oz-50-ml/101229#product-detail-reviews   https://www.iherb.com/r/blithe-pressed-serum-tundra-chaga-1-68-fl-oz-50-ml/101229   False   False   False   False   False   False   10  2   [{'productId': 101229, 'productName': 'Blithe, Pressed Serum, Tundra Chaga, 1.68 fl oz (50 ml)', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/blt/blt66010/s/2.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/blt/blt66010/m/2.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 38.00′,′′:′ 34.20', 'PartNumber': 'BLT-66010'}]    True    False   10.0    False   False   False   0.0 False   0.0
4   Korea, Republic of  kr  5   62027   California Gold Nutrition, Silymarin Complex, Milk Thistle Extract Plus Dandelion, Artichoke, Curcumin C3 Complex®, Ginger, and BioPerine®, 120 Veggie Capsules https://www.iherb.com/pr/california-gold-nutrition-silymarin-complex-milk-thistle-extract-plus-dandelion-artichoke-curcumin-c3-complex-ginger-and-bioperine-120-veggie-capsules/62027   https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/cgn/cgn00956/k/114.jpg    https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/cgn/cgn00956/r/114.jpg    CGN-00956   $14.00  $14.00  False   0   False   False   False   False   0   False   4.8 35521   4.8 of 5 based on 35521 https://www.iherb.com/pr/california-gold-nutrition-silymarin-complex-milk-thistle-extract-plus-dandelion-artichoke-curcumin-c3-complex-ginger-and-bioperine-120-veggie-capsules/62027#product-detail-reviews    https://www.iherb.com/r/california-gold-nutrition-silymarin-complex-milk-thistle-extract-plus-dandelion-artichoke-curcumin-c3-complex-ginger-and-bioperine-120-veggie-capsules/62027    False   False   False   False   False   False   0   114 [{'productId': 62027, 'productName': 'California Gold Nutrition, Silymarin Complex, Milk Thistle Extract Plus Dandelion, Artichoke, Curcumin C3 Complex®, Ginger, and BioPerine®, 120 Veggie Capsules', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/cgn/cgn00956/s/114.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/cgn/cgn00956/m/114.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 14.00′,′′:′ 14.00', 'PartNumber': 'CGN-00956'}] True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
388 Japan   jp  396 7344    Now Foods, B-12, 2,000 mcg, 100 Lozenges    https://www.iherb.com/pr/now-foods-b-12-2-000-mcg-100-lozenges/7344 https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now00459/k/14.jpg https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now00459/r/14.jpg NOW-00459   $9.32   $9.32   False   0   False   False   False   False   0   False   4.8 1198    4.8 of 5 based on 1198  https://www.iherb.com/pr/now-foods-b-12-2-000-mcg-100-lozenges/7344#product-detail-reviews  https://www.iherb.com/r/now-foods-b-12-2-000-mcg-100-lozenges/7344  False   False   False   False   False   False   0   14  [{'productId': 7344, 'productName': 'Now Foods, B-12, 2,000 mcg, 100 Lozenges', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now00459/s/14.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/now/now00459/m/14.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 9.32′,′′:′ 9.32', 'PartNumber': 'NOW-00459'}] True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
389 Hong Kong   hk  397 106622  NutraMedix, Vitamins D3 & K2, 90 Capsules   https://www.iherb.com/pr/nutramedix-vitamins-d3-k2-90-capsules/106622   https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/ndx/ndx09348/k/8.jpg  https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/ndx/ndx09348/r/8.jpg  NDX-09348   $29.95  $29.95  False   0   False   False   False   False   0   False   4.7 46  4.7 of 5 based on 46    https://www.iherb.com/pr/nutramedix-vitamins-d3-k2-90-capsules/106622#product-detail-reviews    https://www.iherb.com/r/nutramedix-vitamins-d3-k2-90-capsules/106622    False   False   False   False   False   False   0   8   [{'productId': 106622, 'productName': 'NutraMedix, Vitamins D3 & K2, 90 Capsules', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/ndx/ndx09348/s/8.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/ndx/ndx09348/m/8.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 29.95′,′′:′ 29.95', 'PartNumber': 'NDX-09348'}]  True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
390 Australia   au  398 2715    Natural Factors, Coenzyme Q10, 100 mg, 60 Softgels  https://www.iherb.com/pr/natural-factors-coenzyme-q10-100-mg-60-softgels/2715   https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/nfs/nfs02071/k/24.jpg https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/nfs/nfs02071/r/24.jpg NFS-02071   $16.07  $16.07  False   0   False   False   False   False   0   False   4.7 7700    4.7 of 5 based on 7700  https://www.iherb.com/pr/natural-factors-coenzyme-q10-100-mg-60-softgels/2715#product-detail-reviews    https://www.iherb.com/r/natural-factors-coenzyme-q10-100-mg-60-softgels/2715    False   False   False   False   False   False   0   24  [{'productId': 2715, 'productName': 'Natural Factors, Coenzyme Q10, 100 mg, 60 Softgels', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/nfs/nfs02071/s/24.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/nfs/nfs02071/m/24.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 16.07′,′′:′ 16.07', 'PartNumber': 'NFS-02071'}] True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
391 Philippines ph  399 46284   Life Extension, Vitamin D3, 25 mcg (1,000 IU), 250 Softgels https://www.iherb.com/pr/life-extension-vitamin-d3-25-mcg-1-000-iu-250-softgels/46284   https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lex/lex17512/k/179.jpg    https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lex/lex17512/r/179.jpg    LEX-17512   $9.75   $9.75   False   0   False   False   False   False   7   False   4.8 2698    4.8 of 5 based on 2698  https://www.iherb.com/pr/life-extension-vitamin-d3-25-mcg-1-000-iu-250-softgels/46284#product-detail-reviews    https://www.iherb.com/r/life-extension-vitamin-d3-25-mcg-1-000-iu-250-softgels/46284    False   False   False   False   False   False   0   179 [{'productId': 46284, 'productName': 'Life Extension, Vitamin D3, 25 mcg (1,000 IU), 250 Softgels', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lex/lex17512/s/179.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/lex/lex17512/m/179.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 9.75′,′′:′ 9.75', 'PartNumber': 'LEX-17512'}]   True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
392 Australia   au  400 104625  I Dew Care, Plush Party, Buttery Vitamin C Lip Mask, 0.42 oz (12 g) https://www.iherb.com/pr/i-dew-care-plush-party-buttery-vitamin-c-lip-mask-0-42-oz-12-g/104625  https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/idc/idc71810/k/13.jpg https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/idc/idc71810/r/13.jpg IDC-71810   $16.00  $16.00  False   0   False   False   False   False   0   False   4.6 73  4.6 of 5 based on 73    https://www.iherb.com/pr/i-dew-care-plush-party-buttery-vitamin-c-lip-mask-0-42-oz-12-g/104625#product-detail-reviews   https://www.iherb.com/r/i-dew-care-plush-party-buttery-vitamin-c-lip-mask-0-42-oz-12-g/104625   False   False   False   False   False   False   0   13  [{'productId': 104625, 'productName': 'I Dew Care, Plush Party, Buttery Vitamin C Lip Mask, 0.42 oz (12 g)', 'iURLSmall': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/idc/idc71810/s/13.jpg', 'iURLMedium': 'https://cloudinary.images-iherb.com/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto:eco/images/idc/idc71810/m/13.jpg', 'listPrice': ' 16.00′,′′:′ 16.00', 'PartNumber': 'IDC-71810'}]  True    False   0.0 False   False   False   NaN NaN NaN
393 rows × 42 columns
```

Data is also saved to a csv file. You probably have some duplicates (I didn't match the AJAX numbers exactly), you can filter them out.

See relevant documentation for the libraries used:

Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

TQDM: https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

And Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/